# Integrity checksum failure while installing API Connect toolkit #apiconnect

Tags: node.js, npm, apiconnect

I'm getting the following error while installing API Connect toolkit:

> sha1-UhOHSxsj+deaxi0QbjKXDirzcn8= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-UhOHSxsj+deaxi0QbjKXDirzcn8= but got sha1-208ds/bfbkHrcce1kMfz2sLUPhs=. (627039 bytes)

Node version:- 6.10.3 
NPM version:- 5.0.1

I'm trying to install API Connect toolkit on a windows 7 workstation (64-bit) using npm install -g apiconnect command.

What could be the next steps for fixing this issue ?

Comment: Please add some code samples or references to make the question more clear so that more people can help you.

Comment: Where are you trying to install from?

Comment: What is your npm registry set to?

Comment: NPM registry was pointing to https://www.npmjs.com/package/apiconnect to pull API Connect developer toolkit.

Comment: If you try it again does that still happen?

Comment: Looks like it was an issue with NPM public repository - I was able to install it successfully after uninstalling Node & NPM.

Answer (score 32):

I encountered this issue, fortunately, I find the solution in
[Github](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16861#issuecomment-305527498):

this is caused by the `package-lock.json`,

so I delete it: `rm package-lock.json`

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

then I execute the `npm install` it works for me.

Comment: After doing stuff like reinstalling npm, cleaning cache, removing node_modules... with no success, deleting package-lock.json is what did the trick

Comment: I searched on goolge for a very long time but no solution works for me. This is the only solution that works!

Answer (score 6):

Go to project dir and enter the following commands in fx powershell or cmd.

```
rm ./package-lock.json
npm cache clear --force
npm install -g npm
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting similar error in Node(v8.1.0) and NPM(5.0.3) Version in Windows 10.
Followed following steps to fix this issue.
a) Uninstalled npm & Node.js completly.
b) Delete "npm" & "npm-cache" folders from "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming" location.
c) Install latest node version through ".msi"
d) from node command prompt run "npm i -g npm"
e) move to your project location and run "npm install" it should work.

Answer (score 4):

I was also getting the same problem but solved by

(1st get older version of npm 4.x.x)

```
npm install -g npm@4.6.1
```

next optional in your case if you are building something and in your project package.lock.json is present  **delete package.lock.json** (it means node version 5 is was installed hance some installers (like while deploying app on Heroku app) automatically detect this file and upgrade to version 5)

*Now Try npm install it should work*

Thank you

Comment: I found that removing the `package-lock.json` file, on a project that did not use it, fixed the error.  It appears that the file versions referenced in `package.json` were not compatible with what had been added to `package-lock.json`, or were not available for that particular version of `node`.  This was on a machine where the developer had downgraded `node` without cleaning the local `node_modules` or `npm`'s cache.

Comment: you saved my day. None of the suggested solution works except downgrading npm as suggested by you.

Answer (score 4):

As of npm 5, you can use [`npm-cache`](https://www.mankier.com/1/npm-cache) to verify the contents of the cache folder, e.g.:

```
npm cache verify
```

Then re-run the `install` again.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions to this problem. I've encountered it many times and always different things helped me.

**A.** At first try cleaning the cache: `npm cache clean --force` then `npm install`

**B.** Second you can try `npm install --update-binary`

**C.** Third option is to try A and delete node_modules folder and then `npm install`

**D.** Fourth option is to uninstall nodejs reboot and reinstall and then try `npm install`

**E.** Last of my options which worked for me was to delete `npm` and `npm-cache` folders in `Users%username%\AppData\Roaming` and running `npm install`

You can try also other combinations usually its best to always do A and clean the cache at least or delete the node_modules folder.

Answer (score 0):

It Must help You :

Simple soultion:

```
sudo npm i npm@latest -g
```

Answer (score -1):

try again, add params ' --unsafe-perm=true '

`npm install -g plugman --unsafe-perm=true`

Answer (score -4):

```
yarn install
```

worked for a similar error. check [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16861)

Comment: `yarn` is completely unrelated to NPM. More detail needs to be provided for this answer.