# EINTEGRITY: npm 5.0 integrity check and modernizr.com dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, modernizr

I've encountered this error when installing deps of my package:

```
$ npm i
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha1-tU7jWojzuU8MIY2VLAx+BwluNo0= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-tU7jWojzuU8MIY2VLAx+BwluNo0= but got sha1-oXYP0kzpbhku0KU+phy353lbBhQ=. (26624 bytes)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tlenex/.npm/_logs/2017-06-22T10_18_19_773Z-debug.log
```

the problem is with my `Modernizr` dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
  "Modernizr": "https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses-flash"
}
```

is there any way to solve this or ignore this integrity check?

Currently I have to run

```
npm i https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses-flash
```

again to get things working, which overrides the `"integrity"` field for `"Modernizr"` in my `package-lock.json`. 
This may happen every time there is a change in `Modernizr` package fetched from this link and my package dependencies need to be reinstalled (for example, each time on CI build)

If there is no other way of solving this? I hope I wont have to place `package-lock.json` in my `.gitignore` file :(

More data about my enviroment:

```
$ npm -v
5.0.3
$ node -v
v6.11.0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integrity checksum failure while installing API Connect toolkit #apiconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331813/integrity-checksum-failure-while-installing-api-connect-toolkit-apiconnect)

Comment: @kenorb It is not. 
It is connected strictly to https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses-flash dependency link, wich **always leads to latest version** of the package and then creates EINTEGRITY error with checksum from package-lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue.

Our team moved away from URL dependency without SEMVER notation, in this case `https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses-flash` and used `modernizr-loader` with `webpack`. There are also equivalents for `gulp` and `grunt` tools available on npm, pick and use one you like the most.

After using them, we finally get rid of returning `EINTEGRITY` npm error without nuking `package-lock.json` or `node_modules`.

Answer (score 5):

Edit package-lock.json , find the one you want to skip in this case the one that its failing

```
sha1-tU7jWojzuU8MIY2VLAx+BwluNo0
```

and remove the integrity parameter from it i.e

```
},
"range-parser": {
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/-/range-parser-1.2.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-9JvmtIeJTdxA3MlKMi9hEJLgDV4=",
  "dev": true
},
```

to...

```
},
"range-parser": {
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/-/range-parser-1.2.0.tgz",
  "dev": true
},
```

after that run npm install, will check the rest, skip this integrity

Comment: Wouldn't `npm install` create this integrity field again in `package-lock.json` ?

Comment: It will, with the new value, I guess this is breaking the purpose of the integrity check, but it clears the issue. Maybe someone else can explain the reason and consecuences. I just find out this as a way to clear and continue.

Answer (score 2):

The point of the integrity field is to alert you when something has changed, so if you do not want it to exist, you can disable package-lock.json files in your npmrc. Just set `package-lock=false`

Note: I am the developer of Modernizr, and spoke with the npm-cli team about this issue. The root cause appears to be the change of the SHA type between npm5 and earlier versions. Nuking the `node_modules` folder will fix it

Comment: Well the point is, that I don't want to disable it for other packages and dependencies.
So nuking the `node_modules` currently is the only option for now.

The perfect solution would be disabling the package-lock SHA check for only one link, domain or package name.

Comment: I also can move to npm's repository "modernizr" package, create own builder and leave this issue unresolved. But currently I'm lacking time to do so.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find all outdated packages and update theme:

   `npm outdated -g`
   `sudo npm i -g outDatedPKG`
2. Upgrade npm to lateste version with:

   `sudo npm i -g npm`
3. Delete `package-lock.json` file.
4. Delete `_cacache` directory in ~/.npm:

   `npm cache verify`

   4.1. Every time i get that error, do steps 2 & 3.
5. If you still get the error, clear npm's cache:

   `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: This is not a good solution when this issue is scaled up on 20+ devs in a team and a lot of CI builds.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error and I solved it by :

1. Deleting package-lock.json
2. Running "npm install"

Comment: This is not a good solution when this issue is scaled up on 20+ devs in a team and a lot of CI builds.

Answer (score -1):

Just do two things for the solution

**first :** 
   npm cache clean --force

**second :** 
   npm i -g npm

and than install what u want

Comment: This is not a good solution when this issue is scaled up on 20+ devs in a team and a lot of CI builds.

Answer (score -1):

- $ rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules
- $ npm install --cache /tmp/empty-npm-cache

If this fixes it, clear your global npm cache to fix the corruption.

Comment: This is not a good solution when this issue is scaled up on 20+ devs in a team and a lot of CI builds. It is connected strictly to modernizr.com/download?setclasses-flash dependency link, wich always leads to latest version of the package and then creates EINTEGRITY error with checksum from package-lock.