# Not able to run npm install json-server

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, rest

I am not able to run the code

```
npm install -g json-server or npm install json-server
```

after running this code in visual studio it says

```
npm warn deprecated request@2.88.2 request has been deprecated, 
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY 
npm ERR! errno EINTEGRITY
```

Please help if anyone know how to solve this issue[this is the error that dont let me run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcA0P.png)

Comment: Does this answer you problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092723/fix-a-npm-install-failure-with-error-code-eintegrity