# npm install throws "integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-6G...= but got sha512..." error

Tags: angular, npm, installation, visual-studio-code

I checked few similar posts on here and other places but was not able to figure out.  Never done Angular but got instructed to install npm and run an angular project I never used before.  Here are the details

On my MacBookPro, I have an existing Angular project I never worked in before.  I open it in VSCode and here is the structure

[image]

If I check version of my npm, I get following:

**Node 10.8.0**

**npm 6.2.0**

, then I go to the parent folder of the **src** folder (so folder that contains the **src** folder) and issue:

```
npm install
```

, I get following output with the error.  Same error is in the log file generated:

```
mycomp:MyProj nbnex$ npm i
WARN tarball tarball data for angular-tree-component@5.2.1 (sha1-6GFJ7dp3tKYSvYAb/EVjK+zOYGQ=) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
WARN tarball tarball data for angular-tree-component@5.2.1 (sha1-6GFJ7dp3tKYSvYAb/EVjK+zOYGQ=) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/dbnex/source/MyProj/MyProj/node_modules/.staging/fsevents-d35eda14/node_modules/yallist' -> '/Users/dbnex/source/MyProj/MyProj/node_modules/.staging/yallist-2c29e2bb'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/dbnex/source/MyProj/MyProj/node_modules/.staging/fsevents-6a393e92/node_modules/set-blocking' -> '/Users/dbnex/source/MyProj/MyProj/node_modules/.staging/set-blocking-5346d4b2'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/dbnex/source/MyProj/MyProj/node_modules/.staging/fsevents-a915511c/node_modules/process-nextick-args' -> '/Users/dbnex/source/MyProj/MyProj/node_modules/.staging/process-nextick-args-7b3b7565'

npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting angular-tree-component@5.2.1:
npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting angular-tree-component@5.2.1:
npm ERR! sha1-6GFJ7dp3tKYSvYAb/EVjK+zOYGQ= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-6GFJ7dp3tKYSvYAb/EVjK+zOYGQ= but got sha512-EUet5nra7Ia1J4AkdJR6ToUFZHPbN9uybPpv+wx5/jo8lch5ezvh/5MQSShxIeU2bvsv4YpcSqgEq/6iBBfgpQ== sha1-dRAb4fP7cqda60ct3CvKQ5zMJxY=. (178201 bytes)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/dbnex/.npm/_logs/2018-10-05T18_04_47_761Z-debug.log
```

Comment: delete package-lock.json and try npm install again

Comment: tried that, did not work

Comment: @ShubhamYerawar this worked for me thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integrity checksum failure while installing API Connect toolkit #apiconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331813/integrity-checksum-failure-while-installing-api-connect-toolkit-apiconnect)

Answer (score 3):

Delete `node_modules` folder. Use `rimraf` to delete the folder faster:

```
npm install rimraf -g
rimraf node_modules
```

Then do

```
 npm install
```

Make sure that you close `VS Code` application. Sometimes it will cause errors if the folder is open in any application.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` file.

Run `npm cache clear --force`

The try again.